# A Timeout error occurs when EC2 and ECS using the same security group communicate

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, subnet, aws-security-group

I'm having trouble communicating with EC2 and ECS.

When I send a request to ECS from EC2 that has the same security group as ECS, I get a Timeout error.
However, the request can be received from ECS from outside.

Security group A allows all its own traffic.

EC2 Instance

- private subnet A
- security group A

ECS Load Balancer(internet facing)

- public subnet A
- security group A (for internal communication)
- security group B (for external communication)

ECS Container

- private subnets A and B
- security group A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send traffic to a public facing load balancer it exits the VPC and comes back in. When the traffic exits the VPC it is no longer associated to a security group. Thus the security group no longer sees the traffic as coming from "itself" and it blocks the request.